# What is an RSA host key?

Tags: ssh, rsa

I get this message saying:

> Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.252.130' to the list of known hosts

What is the meaning of the RSA key and what is the concept behind known hosts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The RSA key is a private key based on the RSA algorithm. The private key is used for authentication and a symmetric key exchange during establishment of an SSL/TLS session.

So this simply means that the host '192.30.252.130' is now a trusted host (one of known hosts) and you can now have a secured connection with this host. This could be used in multiple cases, like using them for logging into your computer(s) via OpenSSH or other secured shell.

Once you connect to a host and the host key is saved to the known_hosts file, your client uses the key to verify all subsequent connections. The same host key information is on the server as well, in case the host key changes, your client would smell something fishy (maybe a [man-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)) and act accordingly.

Refer to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) for details of the RSA algorithm and the process.

Also refer to a similar [question on *Unix and Linux*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/185533/permanently-added-the-rsa-host-key-what-does-it-mean).

Comment: so this means that this is the unique for client and server which both keep with themselves ?

Comment: In essence yes. It's a simple thing. Let's say you connect with a drug dealer on phone and he tells you that his code name is X. So now you remember it. Now let's say you dial the same number and ask him for his code name for the next transaction. Now let's say he tell you a wrong code, you would be able to make out that he's not the dealer but a cop and it's a trap! and you'd hang up the phone!! 
So yes the dealer (server) and you (client) both keep the code (rsa).

Comment: also if you go through wikipedia (link in answer) page, you'd have all the relevant details.

Comment: This is a good answer, I'll add that if any "man-in-the-middle" tries to impersonate the host, since your machine is now aware of the host's public key which the "known hosts" file, then SSH will prompt you an error. (It will detect that the host behind this IP address has changed). The "known_hosts" file is linked to your user account on the machine though.

Comment: So if you re-install the host or change the machine you will get this error too. In that case you can edit the known_hosts file and remove the older record for that host.